# Problems using XDebug with TYPO3 in Netbeans (Symlinks in Vagrant Machine)

Tags: php, netbeans, vagrant, typo3, xdebug

What i want is debugging TYPO3 code with XDebug in a local development environment with Netbeans.

What i have is:

- MacOS Sierra
- Netbeans 8.2
- Vagrant 1.8.7
- Virtualbox 5.1.26
- LAMP stack (Debian Stretch, Apache 2.4, PHP-FPM 7.0, MariaDB 10.1)
- Typo3 8.7.6 (standard mode not composer)

The folder structure of Typo3 is as recommended

```
/typo3_src-8.7.6
/typo3/typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-8.7.6
/typo3/index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
/typo3/typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3
```

The according XDebug params are

```
php_admin_value[xdebug.remote_enable] = 1
php_admin_value[xdebug.remote_host] = 192.168.33.1
php_admin_value[xdebug.remote_port] = 9000
php_admin_value[xdebug.remote_handler] = dbgp
php_admin_value[xdebug.max_nesting_level] = 400
```

The PHP project in Netbeans has set the following path mapping under "Run Configuration" > "Advanced ..":

```
Server Path              Project Path
/var/www/html/typo3      /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3
```

and Netbeans is listening on port 9000 as well as XDebug. The according xdebug.log shows success when starting the debugging:

```
Log opened at 2017-09-16 08:17:52
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.33.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.6/index.php" language="PHP" ..></init>
```

The problem is: XDebug is not recognizing the break points.

When adding an additional path mapping to the typo3 sources

```
Server Path                      Project Path
/var/www/html/typo3              /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3
/var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.6    /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3
```

then Netbeans stops at least at /typo3/index.php when setting up "Stop at first line". But it still does not stop on custom break points in a custom typo3 extension under /typo3/typo3conf/ext/.. . When replacing all symbolic links with their real sources (index.php and typo3), then the debugging works like a charm.

Is there *the* way to solve these path mappings for the symbolic links of a default TYPO3 8 LTS installation?

Comment: Does it help if you add this path maping?: 

`/var/www/html              /Users/{me}/{project}`

Make also sure port 9000 is not used elsewhere,  Try some other port, e.g. 9001 alternatively

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your mapping is not correct. Is it correct that you site root is in /var/www/html/typo3 and you TYPO3 CMS /var/www/html/typo3/typo3 ?

If so the mapping should be something like this:

```
Server Path                              Project Path
/var/www/html/typo3                      /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3
/var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.6            /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3/typo3
/var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.6/index.php  /Users/{me}/{project}/typo3/index.php
```